# how to use ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH intent-filter to start application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to use the intent-filter ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH to make the application do some tasks when it first launched, however it not being captured by the broadcast receiver
my Manifest

```
  <receiver android:name=".reminder.ReminderActionReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

this my broadcast receiver implementation

```
  this.context = context;
    String mAction = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("r", mAction);
    if (mAction == Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED) {

    } else if (mAction == Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH) {


    }
```

How can i make it start when the app first launched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry those intents except for boot_completed are only sent to the play store. But it is relatively simple to do what you need otherwise. Instead use SharedPreferences, like example:

```
public static final String KEY_PREFS_FIRST_LAUNCH = "first_launch";
// ...
SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(prefs.getBoolean(KEY_PREFS_FIRST_LAUNCH, true))
{
    //first launch
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(KEY_PREFS_FIRST_LAUNCH,false).commit();
}
```

Comment: If we cannot use it,the document lists it for what?

Comment: The document is just listing intents, not just ones that we can register to receive, it should really make it more clear though

Comment: @RSenApps nice trick but it will not work! When you edit the SharedPreferences you have to get hold of the Editor and commit the changes! In your case nothing will be saved!