# Android - ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH filter not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I trying to detect my application run at first time. I used Broadcast Receiver to do this. It works fine with ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED. But it doesn't work when I use ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH intent. I'm using Android 4.3

This is my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    broadcastReceiver = new TestBroadcast();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.TestBroadcast" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And TestBroadcast class

```
public class TestBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Application installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot use it in the way you're trying.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17510295/617044

Comment: Why not I can do in this way ? I have use SharePref but it will wrong when use clear cache or data

Answer (score 1):

Applications would receive these intents. These intents are broadcasted only to Play Store.

Comment: So who will receive the intents, applications or Google play store?  Your answer is confusing.